# Geotification vs distance(from: ) Swift 3

Tags: swift3, cllocationmanager

I'm unsure of what process I should use because I dont know the differences between the two.

CLCircularRegion with this you can create a geofence around a specific location.

distance from: just calculates the distance between two points.

My question is whats the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Core Location requires each geofence to be represented as a CLCircularRegion instance before it can be registered for monitoring. Internally CLCircularRegion uses distance calculation between the current position and its own origin and compares the result to its radius.